# How to store a sequence of timestamped data?

Tags: c++, data-structures, deque

I have an application that need to store a sequence of voltage data, each entry is something like a pair {time, voltage}

the time is not necessarily continuous, if the voltage doesn't move, I will not have any reading.

The problem is that i also need to have a function that lookup timestamp, like, getVoltageOfTimestamp(float2second(922.325))

My solution is to have a deque that stores the paires, then for every 30 seconds, I do a sampling and store the index into a map
std::map,

so inside getVoltageOfTimestamp(float2second(922.325)), I simply find the nearest interval_of_30_seconds to the desired time, and then move my pointer of deque to that corresponding_index_of_deque, iterate from there and find the correct voltage.

I am not sure whether there exist a more 'computer scientist' solution here, can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: It would be interesting to know how many ventries you have to store in memory to be able to give a good answer.

Comment: How man entries?  What's the typical time-resolution?  Are there large "holes" in the data?  Is binary search going to be too slow for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a binary search on your `std::deque` because the timestamps are in ascending order.

If you want to optimize for speed, you could also use a `std::map<Timestamp, Voltage>`. For finding an element, you can use `upper_bound` on the map and return the element before the one found by `upper_bound`. This approach uses more memory (because `std::map<Timestamp, Voltage>` has some overhead and it also allocates each entry separately).

Answer (score 1):

Rather then use a separate map, you can do a binary search directly on the deque to find the closet timestamp.  Given the complexity requirements of a std::map, doing a binary search will be just as efficient as a map lookup (both are O(log N)) and won't require the extra overhead.

Comment: Yes, but resizing a `std::vector` is expensive. `std::deque` uses more than one chunk of memory and doesn't need to reallocate and copy every value on resize.

Comment: @hjhill - good point, I'm going to drop the vector recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind using c++ ox conepts ? If not `deque<tuple<Time, Voltage>>` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can improve over binary search is to identify the samples of your data. Assuming your samples are every 30 milliseconds, then in vector/list store the readings as you get them. In the other array, insert the index of the array every 30 seconds. Now given a timestamp, just go to the first array and find the index of the element in the list, now just go there and check few elements preceding/succeeding it.

Hope this helps.